# How friend function works

Tags: c++, class, c++11, operator-overloading, friend-function

I wanted to learn how to use **friend** functions. When attempting it for the first time, I have little problem and I don't know how to fix it.  I got the following errors:

```
|17|error: 'minutes' was not declared in this scope|
|18|error: 'hours' was not declared in this scope|
|24|error: 'minutes' was not declared in this scope|
|24|error: 'minutes' was not declared in this scope|
```

Here's is all the code I have as of now:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Time
{

    int hours;
    int minutes;
    friend Time operator+(const Time & t);
    friend void x(Time h, Time m );

};

Time operator+(const Time & t)
{
    Time sum;
    sum.minutes = minutes + t.minutes;
    sum.hours = hours + t.hours + sum.minutes / 60;
    sum.minutes %= 60;
    return sum;
}


void x(Time h, Time m) {hours = h; minutes = m;}
```

Comment: If you define `operator+` as a non-member function, it must take 2 parameters.

Comment: when you write `sum.minutes = minutes + t.minutes;` then what do you think `minutes` refers to?

Comment: friend functions are not members, just regular functions. Once you get that, all errors should make sense.

Comment: @CássioRenan One *can* have `friend`s that are member functions of a different class.

Comment: @JesperJuhl touché, :). Joking aside: Good point, but it is not the case here, and I don't think it's worth it to get to that point yet, when he's still trying to get the basics.

Comment: @CássioRenan  Just wanted to point out that  "friend functions are not members, just regular functions" is *not* a correct statement in general.

Comment: Doing `hours = h` and `minutes = m` look weird in general because `minutes` and `hours` both are of type `int` whereas `h` and `m` belong to class `Time`.Therefore, your code wouldn't compile even if the function were a member of the class...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These error messages

> |17|error: 'minutes' was not declared in this scope|
>
> |18|error: 'hours' was not declared in this scope|

means that within this function definition

```
Time operator+(const Time & t)
{
    Time sum;
    sum.minutes = minutes + t.minutes;
                  ^^^^^^^
    sum.hours = hours + t.hours + sum.minutes / 60;
                ^^^^^
    sum.minutes %= 60;
    return sum;
}
```

the variables `minutes` and `hours` are not declared. The function is not a member function of the class. So these variables are not data members of an object of the class `Time`. They are undeclared identifiers.

Friend functions do not get the implicit argument `this`  as non-static member class functions do.

These error messages

> |24|error: 'minutes' was not declared in this scope|
>
> |24|error: 'minutes' was not declared in this scope|

have the same meaning. The function `x` is not a member function of the class Time.

If the friend function `operator +` overloads the binary operator `+` then it shall have two parameters.

As for the second friend function then it seems its task is to set values for an object of the type `Time`.

The friend functions should be declared and defined the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

class Time
{
    int hours;
    int minutes;
    friend Time operator +( const Time &t1, const Time &t2 );
    friend void x( Time &t, int h, int m );
    friend std::ostream & operator <<( std::ostream &is, const Time &t );
};

Time operator +( const Time &t1, const Time &t2 )
{
    const int HOURS_IN_DAY = 24;
    const int MINUTES_IN_HOUR = 60;

    Time t;

    t.hours  = t1.hours + t2.hours + ( t1.minutes + t2.minutes ) / MINUTES_IN_HOUR;
    t.hours %= HOURS_IN_DAY;
    t.minutes = ( t1.minutes + t2.minutes ) % MINUTES_IN_HOUR;

    return t;
}

void x( Time &t, int h, int m )
{
    t.hours = h;
    t.minutes = m;
}

std::ostream & operator <<( std::ostream &os, const Time &t )
{
    return 
    os << std::setw( 2 ) << std::setfill( '0' ) << t.hours 
       << ':'
       << std::setw( 2 ) << std::setfill( '0' ) << t.minutes; 
}

int main() 
{
    Time t1;

    x( t1, 16, 10 );

    std::cout << t1 << '\n';

    Time t2;

    x( t2, 10, 20 );

    std::cout << t2 << '\n';

    std::cout << t1 + t2 << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
16:10
10:20
02:30
```

Comment: It is  possible the OP is confusing member functions with friend functions.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont It seems he thinks that friend functions behave as non-static member functions.

Answer (score 1):

When you write:

```
class Time
{
    friend Time operator+(const Time & t);
};
```

Then `operator+` is not a member function. It is a free function and the line in the class declaration only declares that this function is a friend of the class `Time`.

As a non-member, the binary `operator+` has to take 2 parameters. Consider how you would use it:

```
Time a,b;
Time c = a + b;
```

You need to pass `a` and `b` and return a new `Time` `c`:

```
Time operator+(const Time & t1,const Time& t2)
{
    Time sum;
    sum.minutes = t1.minutes + t2.minutes;
    sum.hours = t1.hours + t2.hours + sum.minutes / 60;
    sum.minutes %= 60;
    return sum;
}
```

You have similar problem with `x`, but I don't understand what it is supposed to do. If you understand the issue with `operator+` you should also be able to fix that.

Comment: A non-member `+` can take 1 argument.  I'm positive!  http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8d59f01be2f0f8d3 It does, however, not add up.  It is just positive.  Like, the opposite of negative.

Answer (score 0):

`friend` functions/classes are functions/classes that can access `private` and `protected` members.

A friend function is not a member function f the class it is declared friend of so it doesn't have the implicit pointer `this` so in:

```
void x(Time h, Time m) {hours = h; minutes = m;} // doesn't compile
```

Because as long as `hours` and `minutes` are data members of an object of type class `Time` you need to access them via an object of that class.

- let' assume your class `Time` has a member function named `setMinutes()` which is defined as:

  ```
  int Times::SetMinutes(int h, int m)
  {
         hours = h; // in fact it is translated as: this->hours = h;
         this->minutes = m;
  }
  ```
- As you may have seen the insertion operator `<<` be overloaded by a class this way:

  ```
  friend std:ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Time& rhs) // friend here is only to access private and protected members
  {
          out << rhs.hours << " " << rhs.minutes; // not out << hours << minutes;   * if the keyword `friend` is removed then this line will not compile: "accessing private members".
          return out;
  }
  ```
- Also the declaration of `+` operator is incorrect:

  ```
  friend Time operator+(const Time & t);
  ```

Because `+` is a binary operator thus it needs two operands "lhs" and "rhs" so you can:

```
     friend Time operator+(const Time & lsh, const Time& rhs);
```

Or:

```
     Time operator+(const Time & t); // OK
```

- The second version works because the `+` is a member function: which means it uses the object on which the operator called as the "lhs" through de-referencing `this` and the argument `t` as "rhs".
- The preferred version is the `friend` one.

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818: The unary version is used as the positive sign of the object; if it is declared as a member function then it must take 0 argument otherwise if as `friend` then it must take an argument. But the OP here doesn't know that he/she is implementing the unary version not the binary one which he/she intends.